# Mongoose query returns nothing, while MongoDB query returns expected results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to filter for dates in a range, but I've gotten so frustrated that I'm now just trying to query for dates that are less than the current time.

I have this query:

```
q = { 'recorded_timestamp': { '$lt': '2018-09-12T21:02:05.187Z' } };
```

I've also tried the following queries and none of them work:

```
q2 = { 'recorded_timestamp': { '$lt': new Date() } };
q3 = { 'recorded_timestamp': { '$lt': new Date(Date.now()) } };
q4 = { 'recorded_timestamp': { '$lt': new Date().toISOString() } };
```

When I try to do `MyModel.find(q)`, I get nothing back. However, if I copy that query exactly into a MongoDB shell, I'm getting the results that I expect.

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  const results = MyModel.find(q)
  resolve(results);
});
return promise.then(results => {
  return results; // results = [], but they shouldn't
});
```

What's going on here?

- Mongoose version: 4.13.14
- MongoDB version: 3.4.17
- Node version: 8.11.2

Here's a relevant excerpt of the model:

```
const MySchema = new Schema({
  some_ID: {
    type:     String,
    required: true
  },
  recorded_timestamp: {
    type:     Date,
    required: true
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('MyModel', MySchema);
```

Here's a snippet of the sample data that gets inserted into the collection.

```
{ "some_ID": "16499", "recorded_timestamp": "2007-03- 13T07:39:52.959057" }
{ "some_ID": "17158",  "recorded_timestamp": "2007-09- 12T15:31:18.244142" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback to see the result.

```
MyModel.find(q, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. I was just showing what the query looks like. Thank you, though. I'll edit my question to demonstrate that I'm doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the big JSON file that inserts a bunch of sample data was storing the values as strings (which is why `q = { 'recorded_timestamp': { '$lt': '2018-09-12T21:02:05.187Z' } }` worked when executed in a MongoDB shell.)

I changed the type of 'recorded_timestamp' in my schema to be a string and now it is working.

This thread helped me diagnose my issue: [Mongoose Queries on Date Condition Have No Results, MongoDB Shell Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208807/mongoose-queries-on-date-condition-have-no-results-mongodb-shell-works?rq=1)